# Non-greedy regex quantifier gives greedy result

Tags: .net, regex, non-greedy

I have a .net regex which I am testing using Windows Powershell. The output is as follows:

```
> [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match("aaa aaa bbb", "aaa.*?bbb")


Groups   : {aaa aaa bbb}
Success  : True
Captures : {aaa aaa bbb}
Index    : 0
Length   : 11
Value    : aaa aaa bbb
```

My expectation was that using the `?` quantifier would cause the match to be `aaa bbb`, as the second group of a's is sufficient to satisfy the expression. Is my understanding of non-greedy quantifiers flawed, or am I testing incorrectly?

Note: this is plainly not the same problem as [Regular Expression nongreedy is greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246232/9967)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding. Lazy quantifiers do not guarantee the shortest possible match. They only make sure that the current quantifier, from the current position, does not match more characters than needed for an overall match.

If you truly want to ensure the shortest possible match, you need to make that explicit. In this case, this means that instead of `.*?`, you want a subregex that matches anything that is neither `aaa` nor `bbb`. The resulting regex will therefore be

```
aaa(?:(?!aaa|bbb).)*bbb
```

Comment: I just did what I should have done in the first place, and consulted the relevant chapter of Friedl. That led me to `aaa((?!aaa).)*bbb`, which is more or less what you said, except that your answer has the added details of making the subexpression non-capturing and also tests for bbb in the negative lookahead. Nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

Compare the result for the string `aaa aaa bbb bbb`:

```
regex: aaa.*?bbb 
result: aaa aaa bbb

regex: aaa.*bbb
result: aaa aaa bbb bbb
```

The regex engine finds first occurrence of `aaa` and then skips all characters (`.*?`) until *first* occurrence of `bbb`, but for the greedy operator (`.*`) it will go on to find a larger result and therefore match the *last* occurrence of `bbb`.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation of what's happening. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is not a greedy/lazy problem. The problem comes to the fact that your string is analysed from left to right. When the first `aaa` is matched, the regex engine add characters one by one to have the complete pattern.

Note that with a greedy behaviour, in your example, you obtain the same result: the first `aaa` is matched, the regex engine take all the last characters and backtrack character by character until having the complete match.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's really simple, we have the following string

> aaa aaa bbb

Let's see we have this regex `aaa.*?bbb`. The regex engine will start with `aaa`

> **aaa** aaa bbb

The regex engine has now `.*?bbb`. It will proceed with the `space`

> aaa **space** aaa bbb

but we still have some characters until `bbb` ? So the regex engine will continue it's way and match the second set of a

> aaa **aaa space** bbb

Finally the regex engine will match `bbb`:

> aaa aaa **bbb**

---

So let's see, if we only want to match the second `aaa` we could use the following regex:

`(?<!^)aaa.*?bbb`, this means to match `aaa` that is not at the beginning of the sentence.

We may also use `aaa(?= bbb).*?bbb`, this means to match `aaa` that is followed by `space bbb`.

See it working **[1](http://regex101.com/r/lW0sT8)** - **[2](http://regex101.com/r/nJ0uX6)**.

Just came to my senses, but why don't you directly use `aaa bbb` ?