# Issue getting the shortest match using optional groups

Tags: javascript, regex, vba, vbscript, non-greedy

I want to allow any 0 to 2 characters between each group in the `(this is)?.??.??(an)?.??.??(example sentence)` regex. It should match the bolded text in the below strings:

> blah blah. An **example sentence**
>   blah blah. **This is an example sentence**
>   Something something **Example sentence**

Now, in the first example, the match is `ah. example sentence`.  I thought adding 2 question marks to "." would mean that the regex engine will prefer to match 0 chars.

I'm using regex within VBA in MS Word, implemented by `CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")`, which as I understand it uses the VBScript regex flavor, which as I understand it is the same as the JavaScript flavor.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew why is this a duplicate?  As far as I can see I'm using non greedy on purpose, but getting a greedy match.  This isn't addressed in the linked question.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how greedy and lazy quantifiers work. The linked thread deals with that. Quantifiers do not affect the place where a match is found. A regex engine parses text from left to right. Once it can match a part of the text with a pattern, it will.

Comment: (this is).*?(an).*?(example sentence)

Comment: @LonnieBest Thank you, but I want to match a maximum of two characters between each subexpression, and match even if the subexpression is absent

Comment: I think you need to modify the question to accentuate the real problem. It seems to me you just need to use the `.{0,2}` (or even `.{1,2}`) inside the optional groups, `(this is.{0,2})?(an.{0,2})?(example sentence)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ONhZRD/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That solves the problem thanks.  Why does placing it outside the groups matter though? When searching `0020002101` should `2.??.??.??101` not prefer `2101` to `20002101`?

Comment: Regex egine cannot "prefer" anything. It matches from left to right. Once the `2` is found (the first `2`) it starts matching the subsequent subpatterns, and when a match is found, it is returned.

Comment: I do think [Non-greedy regex quantifier gives greedy result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633315/non-greedy-regex-quantifier-gives-greedy-result) is a better dupe for this question.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx was the reference I was using by the way.  Very misleading: | ?? | Matches the previous element zero or one time, but as few times as possible. |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When searching `0020002101` should `2.??.??.??101` not prefer `2101` to `20002101`?

Regex egine cannot "prefer" anything. It matches from left to right. Once the `2` is found (the first `2`) it starts matching the subsequent subpatterns, and when a match is found, it is returned.

In your case, you need to use the `.{0,2}` *inside the optional groups*,

```
(this is.{0,2})?(an.{0,2})?(example sentence)
        ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ONhZRD/2).

If the order of the optional strings is important, make them nested:

```
(this is.{0,2}(an.{0,2})?)?(example sentence)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ONhZRD/4). This regex will only match `an` with 0 to 2 chars after it only if `this is` with 0 to 2 chars is found before it.

Comment: Thank you.  This clarifies things a lot.

Comment: Was experimenting a bit with this one and modifying the original regex to `(this is)??.??.??(an)??.??.??(example sentence)` I'd expect  only **example sentence** to be matched but... [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ONhZRD/5). The first two groups get matched any way. Any idea why?

Comment: A hint: switch to PCRE regex flavor at regex101.com and click *regex debugger*. You will see the internals of matching that is quite common to these NFA regex engines. Your matches are expected. If you need to avoid returning a match at all, you would have to use lookarounds/zero-width assertions that restrict a match context and do not return the matched texts with the match value.